# Fastest way to get the Ajax callbacks

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table called 'items' which has 10 rows. This 'items' table contain 2 columns(id, item_name). item_name is where I store the images' names such as item_fdsj43.jpg, item_bdf34.jpg, and so on...

If I want to displayed all these images, I do something like this:

```
fetching.php:

$query = "SELECT item_name FROM items";
$mysql_query = mysql_query($query);

while($mysql_fetch_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_query)){
  $mysql_fetch_assoc_item_name = $mysql_fetch_assoc['item_name'];
  echo 'img/'.$mysql_fetch_assoc_item_name;

}


JAVASCRIPT

$('fetching.php', function(data)){
  $('#inner_container').append(data);
});
```

This will display all the data simultaneously and append it on '#inner_container' once the fetching is done. However, this callbacks takes a while and slower compare to search engine of this website (http://www.bedbathstore.com/). Is there any way to boost its speed?

Comment: get a better internet connection.

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: "$('fetching.php', .....". Are you sure there's not something missing there? Something like `.get()` maybe? Otherwise, where is the ajax call?

Answer (score 0):

Here i can suggest to you `JSON` instead of output data using `echo` below are the sample code

you can modify it for your needs

**PHP code**

```
ob_start();
imagepng($my_img);
$imageData = ob_get_contents();
ob_clean(); 

$results = array(
  'price' => $_GET['priceX'],
  'image' => base64_encode($imageData)
);

$json = json_encode($results);
echo $json;
```

**Javascript code:**

```
$.getJSON("/ajax-script.php", function(data) {
  $("#element").append($("<img />").attr('src', 'data:image/png;charset=utf8;base64,' + data.image));
});
```

Comment: yes if you want to utilize for search engine as i guess you should define your image name relevant to your key words search or items.

Answer (score 0):

You can use json to retrieve the image paths at once from the server asynchronously and then you can append these images to image container like this,

```
//fetching.php:

$query = "SELECT item_name FROM items";
$mysql_query = mysql_query($query);
$file_names = array();

while($mysql_fetch_assoc = mysql_fetch_assoc($mysql_query)){
    $mysql_fetch_assoc_item_name = $mysql_fetch_assoc['item_name'];
    array_push($file_names, 'img/'.$mysql_fetch_assoc_item_name);
}

echo json_encode($file_names);
```

//JAVASCRIPT

```
$.getJSON("fetching.php", function(data) {
    $.each(data, function() {
    $('#inner_container').append($("<img />").attr('src', this);
    });
});
```